# Organic Groups Create Content Link does not appear

Tags: organic-groups

When I log in with my administrator account I am able to see the Create Content Link in my Organic Group. But when I am logged in with another account - permission to create content for content types is set - the create content link does not appear. I also activated [entityreference prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate). Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which permission you mean with the "Permission to create content for content type is set" (consider adding the URL within admin to clarify that, is it `/admin/people/permissions`?).

However, it could well be that your issue is because you've not yet completed the "OG Permissions" located with something like `/admin/config/group/permissions/` (and then select the 'edit' link for the group type your issue is about).